# Active directory in php with shell_exec

Tags: php, active-directory, windows-server-2012

I am working on the Active Directory using PHP (Xampp). My task is to add the user to their respective groups. its run perfectly on my local system with configuration (Xampp, php7.1, windows 7). When I migrate it to the windows server 2012, it's showing an error here is my sample code :

```
shell_exec("dsadd user cn={$username},ou={$school},ou=Students,ou=Users,ou=xxx,dc=xx,dc=com -fn \"{$firstName}\" -ln \"{$lastName}\" -email {$email}  -display {$username} -pwd {$password} 2>&1"); shell_exec("dsmod group cn=ISE-PARENTS,ou=\"App_Parents & Students\",ou=Groups,ou=Users,ou=xx,dc=xx,dc=com -addmbr cn={$fatherUsername},ou=Parents,ou=Users,ou=xxx,dc=xx,dc=com 2>&1");
```

[image: showing error]

If I run on CMD it's run perfectly on windows server 2012.
Please help me to get rid of this error. I don't understand why this error occurs?

Comment: To me it sounds like a PHP web server permission error. Exactly how are you executing the PHP script on the production server? (Apache, IIS, or console). Generally speaking the web server would need to be configured to run PHP with a user permissible of adding users for the associated `shell_exec` to function. e.g. what does a PHP script with `<?php echo shell_exec('whoami');` say, and does it have `dsadd user` permission

Comment: I also suggest looking into using [`ldap`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-add.php) functions instead of relying on `shell_exec`

Comment: @fyrye I am using Apache web server. How will I give permission? yes, I am showing code exactly that I am executing.But same shell_exec function I am using for google app manager. It's worked but for  `dsadd` it's showing error

Comment: Server environments are typically much more restrictive than workstations. Find out the user account that is executing the php `shell_exec` and add it to the domain admins group (not advisable as it gives external web access domain admins rights), or explicitly configure your virtual webserver to run php as a user that has permission, such as with `php-fpm` and `mod_proxy_fcgi` again using `ldap` would allow you to `bind` the correct user to issue the commands as opposed to potentially compromising your server security.

Comment: @fyrye User is already in domain admin group

Comment: Which "user" are you referring? As the user is generally assigned to the service, it will NOT be the user accessing the script from the browser.

Comment: @fyrye I log in as an administrator user and run a script as a localhost still show same error